# Mac OSX SwiftUI app bar: executing terminal command fails

Tags: swift, bash, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to execute a simple command in the terminal from a Mac OS X app that I've just created with SwiftUI:

```
func run(_ executableURL: URL, arguments: [String]? = nil) throws -> String {
        let process = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()
        
        process.standardOutput = pipe // you can also set stderr and stdin
        process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
        process.arguments = ["-c", "ipconfig getifaddr en0"]
        
        try! process.run()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        
        guard let standardOutput = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            FileHandle.standardError.write(Data("Error in reading standard output data".utf8))
            fatalError()
        }
        return standardOutput
    }
```

And when I'm running this function, I'm getting `ipconfig_server_port failed (os/kern) unknown error code (44c)` regardless of whether I run it with `en0` or `en1`, or even `/bin/zsh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Thanks!

Comment: *Just created* new projects are sandboxed by default where `Process` is not allowed.

Comment: ah thanks! very newbie here :)